# Meteor.JS when Page navigation on Button Click ,Page loads for a second and again previous page appears

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Code For LoginRegister.html
          1.Main Page 
          2.All the templates are working fine.I think there is no issue regarding the html file 
          3.Problem is in the router.js file

```
         <!--Home Template !-->
         <template name="home">
         {{> login}}
         </template>

         <!--Layout Template !-->
         <template name="layout"> 
             <header>
               {{> topheader }}
             </header>
             {{> yield}}  
         </template>

         <!--TopHeader Template !-->
         <template name="topheader">  
                <h1>Welcome</h1>        
         </template>

         <!--Login Template !-->
         <template name="login">  
           <form class="form-horizontal">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default signin" id="signInBtn ">Sign in</button>         
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default signup" id="signUpBtn ">Sign Up</button>        
          </form>
         </template>

         <!--SignUP Template !-->
         <template name="signup">   
                <h1>SIGNUP <small>Page</small></h1>     
         </template>
```

**Router.js**
This works correctly , When SignUp button is clicked , it flashes sigup template but again reloads home template with login page

                                  `Router.configure({
                layoutTemplate: 'layout'

              });
             Router.map(function()
             {
                this.route('home',{path: '/'});
                this.route('signup',{path: '/signup'}); 
             })`

**loginRegister.js**
Java Script File containing events for Both Button Click

```
          if (Meteor.isClient) {     
           Template.login.events({
                'click .signin': function(evt,tmpl){

                        alert("Sign in button is clicked");
                       console.log("Registration Form submitted.");

                 },
                 'click .signup':function(evt,tmpl)
                 {
                    Router.go('signup', {name: '/signup'});

                 }
           });   
       }
```

Please help I am stuck and I am new to Meteor so unable to figure it out , and search does not generated good result

Comment: Router.go('/signup')

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent your button from submitting, so try something like this in your signup event handler code:

```
'click .signup':function(evt,tmpl)
{
  evt.preventDefault(); // add this to prevent the button from submitting
  Router.go('signup', {name: '/signup'});
}
```